# Using regex to delete a username in Python

Tags: python, regex, normalization, data-cleaning

I have a code like that uses a regular expression to delete a "username" from a text

```
# remove mention, link, hashtag
text = ' '.join(re.sub("([@#][A-Za-z0-9]+)|(\w+:\/\/\S+)"," ", text).split())
```

However it does not work in all cases, for example, the below username does not seem to be deleted:

```
@username_user
```

In fact, it only works on first part of the username, before the underscore, leaving me with the below:

```
user
```

How can I adapt my code in order to work on the entire username provded in the example?

Comment: Is `@_` valid? Try `[@#][A-Za-z0-9]+(?:_[A-Za-z0-9]+)*|\w+:\/\/\S+` https://regex101.com/r/p8KDFx/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you need is just adapting your **regex** to match more patterns of usernames, like **@username_user**, then you can add the underscore in your first group, as below:

```
text = ' '.join(re.sub("([@#][A-Za-z0-9_]+)|(\w+:\/\/\S+)"," ", text).split())
```

The above will work with "**@username_user**", and you can adapt it to as many new character as you need, by adding them after the underscore in the character set (the square brackets; after the number 9) of the regex.